# Show requests from root folder to subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm using Laravel for my website, but i'm encountering a problem.

My website does not have any **public_html** or **htdocs** folder, but the root itself it is already public. Because of this i'm obliged to put all the Laravel files to the root folder.

To who doesn't know, when using Laravel the public folder is generally the subfolder **public**, therefore right now if I want to access my Laravel web applicaton I have to navigate to http://www.mywebsite.com/public.

I need to edit the .htaccess in order to show from http://www.mywebsite.com/ the subfolder **public** files and deny any access to the root files.

So http://www.mywebsite.com/public/index.php should be http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php, http://www.mywebsite.com/public/images/logo.png should be http://www.mywebsite.com/images/logo.png and so on.

Now I'm wondering, is it even possible?

Laravel .htaccess original file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been successful to solve this myself by editing the original .htaccess to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```